# How to add parameter to aggregate function in report dataset

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting-services, expression, reportbuilder3.0

Thank you for coming to look at my question.

I have an SQL group by function which I'd like to add parameters to. (If that's possible)

I've tried to splice the parameters, two columns from the table into the function but I don't seem to get it right.

This function creates a table that counts records, I would like to be able to filter with parameters by 'Team' and 'Location'.
How would I go about adding this information to the dataset to allow me to filter?

I would normally add them using:

```
select
i.Team
,i.Location
From 
incident i
Where i.Team  in (@Team)
and i.Location in (@Location)
```

The table is called incident and all the information is from the same table.

I would very much appreciate an idea to do this. Thank you.

Oh, and I'm using Report Builder 3, with SQL 2008 R2

```
declare @st_date datetime;
declare @en_date datetime;
declare @days int;
declare @offset int;
set @en_date = (@en_datein);
set @offset = (@BrowserTimezoneOffset);
set @days = -6;
set @st_date = DATEADD(dd, @days, @en_date);

with daterange(dt) as
(select 
@st_date dt
union all
select 
DATEADD(dd, 1, dt) dt 
from daterange
where dt <= DATEADD(dd, -1, @en_date)
)
select
             left(DATENAME(dw, dt), 3) as weekday
            ,ISNULL(sum(inc.createdc), 0) as createdcount
            ,ISNULL(sum(inr.resolvedclosedc), 0) as resolvedclosedcount
from daterange left outer join
(select
left(DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(mi,@offset,CreatedDateTime)), 3) as createddatetime
,count(recid) as createdc
from Incident
where DATEADD(mi,@offset,CreatedDateTime) >= @st_date
and DATEADD(mi,@offset,CreatedDateTime) <= @en_date
group by  left(DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(mi,@offset,CreatedDateTime)), 3)
) as inc
on inc.CreatedDateTime = left(DATENAME(dw, dt), 3)
left outer join
(select
left(DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(mi,@offset,ResolvedDateTime)), 3) as ResolvedDateTime
,count(case when status in ('Resolved', 'Closed') then 1 end) as resolvedclosedc
from Incident
where DATEADD(mi,@offset,ResolvedDateTime) between @st_date and @en_date
group by  left(DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(mi,@offset,ResolvedDateTime)), 3)
) as inr
on inr.ResolvedDateTime = left(DATENAME(dw, dt), 3)
group by dt
order by dt
```

Answer (score 0):

When using parameters that will be using one or many values you may tie them to a dataset as well.

Say if I have orders and people in a pretend sequence but I want to find orders of only certain people.  I would follow a few steps:

1. I would create a dataset only for a parameter and call it 'People' for this example lets use a table variable that self executes and place this 'Query' box for a dataset.

   ```
   declare @People Table ( personID int identity, person varchar(8));

   insert into @People values ('Brett'),('Sean'),('Chad'),('Michael')
   ,('Ray'),('Erik'),('Queyn');

   select * From @People
   ```
2. I would want to start with the dependency first which is a variable @Person I set up as an Integer and check 'Allow multiple values'.  I then choose 'Available Values' on the left pane of the variable.  I choose 'Get values from a query' choose my 'people' dataset from 1, choose PersonID as the Value field, and person as the label.
3. Now my parameter is bound and I can move on to my orders set.  Again create a Dataset but call this one 'OrdersMain' and use a self extracting table variable but I am adding a predicate now referencing my variable from above as well.

   ```
   declare @Orders table ( OrderID int identity, PersonID int, Desciption varchar(32), Amount int);

   insert into @Orders values (1, 'Shirt', 20),(1, 'Shoes', 50),(2, 'Shirt', 22),
   (2, 'Shoes', 52),(3, 'Shirt', 20),(3, 'Shoes', 50),(3, 'Hat', 20),
   (4, 'Shirt', 20),(5, 'Shirt', 20),(5, 'Pants', 30), (6, 'Shirt', 20),
   (6, 'RunningShoes', 70),(7, 'Shirt', 22),(7, 'Shoes', 40),(7, 'Coat', 80)

   Select * from @Orders where PersonID in (@Person)
   ```
4. Now if populate my report with a tablix item and put the values from 'OrdersMain' in a tablix a user is prompted with a label for Brett, Sean, etc.. but the id is used for the orders to limit the scope of the dataset.

**Optional**

You can repeat step 1 for a SUBSET of people in another dataset and call it 'Defaults'.  Then with an expanse of step 2 leave everything as is, but add this new dataset to 'Default Values' get from a query.  This way I could create a temp table to get some of my people I most often use and then set them to be defaults instead.  This would make the report auto execute when called.

Filtering can mean other things in SSRS as well.  You can on any dataset see on the left pane a 'filter' and you may apply this.  Keep in mind this will evaluate the whole expression first and then filter it.  This use IMHO is best with shared datasets that are rather small and fast.  Or you can use the filter clause in tablix elements as well which often is good when you want three objects from the same set but different predicates evaluated after runtime but to limit scope with reuse of one dataset for many objects.

Comment: Thank you very much djangojazz. This has helped me to understand parameters a lot better. I am working with a chart in this report, is there anything else that I need to take into account, regarding what you've advised? With my group query, can I easily add in another parameter as you've detailed above?

Comment: Yes, keep in mind the datasets in SSRS do NOT have to be for presentation.  They can be ONLY used for populating variables.  I do this a lot for multi or single select combo parameters for users.  Their is not a hard limit I am familiar with and some reports I have eight datasets with only one being for display.  You may also have a list determine another list with a dependent variable first.  EG: I make up a parameter departments and then it selects a value that then gets used from something like select * from @People where Dept in(@Depts).  This then has one parameter be DEPENDENT on another

Comment: Technically Parameters are also for presentation but what I meant is that datasets don't have to just be on a grid or chart.  They can be used to populate variables, determine a workflow process internally, or just filter data further.